# How to get last month and year from the SYSDATE in expression transformation in informatica powercenter

Tags: datetime-format, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Currently I'm trying to get the last month and year as 'Mon YYYY' format in an expression transformation.

Here's the logic in the expression transformation,

```
to_char(trunc(add_to_date(sysdate,'MONTH',-1),'MONTH'))
```

The column data type is string.

My desired output is 'Nov 2019' if the current date is 'Dec 2019'.

Am I doing it right? Need some guideline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is confusing.   Still, assuming your input date string is in 'dd/mm/yyyy' format then, 
If you want to get Mon YYYY format from a string then use -
to_char( to_date(date_str,'dd/mm/yyyy') , 'Mon YYYY')

If you want last month of date_str then
to_char( add_to_date(to_date(date_str,'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'MM',-1) , 'Mon YYYY')

If you want last month of sysdate then
to_char( add_to_date(sysdate, 'MM',-1) , 'Mon YYYY')